# I want to add label on only specific vue chart

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

[image]

I added the labels on vue pie chart using vue-chartjs and chartjs-plugin-labels module.
But they are displayed on all charts.
I want to display the labels on only specific chart.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont register it globally but only locally in the plugins array it will only activate for that chart

Example (only the first chart will have labels):

```
var chart = {
  type: 'pie',
  plugins: [chartjsPluginDatalabels],
  data: {},
  options: {}

var chart2 = {
  type: 'pie',
  plugins: [],
  data: {},
  options: {}
```

Codepen live example: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/yLgmmyd